# How to get value of self.navigationItem.title and set as new variable?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

On a detail view I'm trying to pull the navigation item's title which is dynamically set from my UITableView. I want to set it as an NSString value - so for example if my title is "potatoes" I want to get that string and set it as a variable in my view controller.

Here's the code I have so far. I tried setting this new variable as my UILabel text and it always outputs the string "Detail" - I can never seem to get the actual title value.

```
NSString *theTitleValue = self.navigationItem.title;
self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = theTitleValue;
```

I should point out that if I manually set a string to my description label (UILabel) it works fine. Only when I'm pulling the self.navigationitem.title does it come back as 'Detail'

```
self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = @"Some stuff here LMAO!!!";
```

So the single line above will output that string in my label. Any thoughts on how I can get the literal string value of my current navigation item?

EDIT:
Here is the code from my table view which pushes this new detail view and title setting. Is there alternatively a way to pass this variable from the table view into the detail view?

What I mean is the value of currentLabel is exactly what I need to grab. However this code below is from MasterViewController.m and I need the currentLabel variable inside DetailViewController.m. I don't know of any way to pass variables between view controllers, so in my mind the easiest way to solve this would be pulling the value from the DetailViewController's navigation title.

```
# MasterViewController.m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // creating NSString value for current vegetable in array
    NSString *currentLabel = [self.vegetablesListing objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    DetailViewController *detailVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VegetablesDetailViewCont"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
    detailVC.navigationItem.title = currentLabel;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is set the new UIViewController's title directly, even along with the navigation controller's title. Then in your new detail view just call `self.title` to pull out the value.

example codes:

```
DetailViewController *detailVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewName"];
detailVC.title = currentLabel;
detailVC.navigationItem.title = currentLabel;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
```

then in your detail controller you can check this value with NSLog:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.title);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title;
```

Comment: the weird this is I tried that, but it pulls the label from my UITableView instead. So with that value I get the label text "vegetables" for every vegetable detail view in my list - potatoes, carrots, green beans, etc. Maybe I am setting up the main detail wrong? I editing my original post above with more code.

Comment: Inside of my table view I have the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method. In here I'm setting the variable `*currentLabel` which pulls dynamic data from an array and populates my table. I need to pass this String value onto the next page - I'm already doing that by setting the navigationItem.title, so I figure I could just pull this value instead. The code you gave me above is pulling the TableView title, NOT the detailView title. That's the issue I'm running into - if I can offer more information please ask. But I'm still fairly new in Obj-C so it's a bit of a struggle.

Comment: I will likely have to just open another question.. I feel maybe this is a bit too confusing with poor wording.